# Running a script when clicking on a google map marker

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want the users of my site to be able to click on a Google map marker and be redirected to a page relating to this marker. The markers represent hotels and the related page shows various bits of information about the particular hotel. This page is created using PHP calls to a SQL database so I cannot simply supply the URL to the marker as it needs to know which hotel was clicked on to populate the page with the relavent info.

Is it possible to run a script upon clicking the marker rather than a redirect to a URL? That way I can make the calls to the database using PHP in the script and create the page and load it up. What I would need is just some (hidden) information sent from the marker to the script which would determine which hotels marker had been clicked.

Comment: Yes it is possible to run a script when a marker is clicked.  See [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events)

Comment: I'm not sure to get you. Your markers does not know which hotel they represents and so you have to query the database in order to know that?

Comment: @sabotero The markers are generated using latitude/longitude data from the SQL table. When they are clicked I want to refer back to the table to retrieve the rest of the information about that particular hotel and display it on a separate web page. Feasible?

Comment: Well, Yes but you can put the rest of information as you create your marker as least, say, the "hote_id" which you can pass in de url, for example: `yourhotelsurl.com/hotels?id=hotel_id`

Comment: @Giovanni please check out my suggested approach in my answer below. If you think is not helpful please post some code in order to be able to help further!

Comment: @Giovanni did you get over this?

Comment: Sorry, havent got to this yet, hit a stumbling block in another bit of the site, but I will be getting back to this in the next week!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to get a look to a different approach exposed in the example code below.

Basically you still get the latitude/longitude information from the data base, but at the same time you get other *helpful information*.

I simulate in the example that we are getting `id` information from data base as that, normally, should be enough, but you can as well, get other information that you might need.

We create a object (`MyMarker`) that encapsulate all the information, and a collection object (`MyMarkerCollection`) to help manage several `MyMarker` objects.

Then when you click in the marker you pass the *helpful information* by the URL and you can build your page saving one query to the server with no cost.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>    
    <title>Handling markers collection demo</title>

   <style type="text/css">
        html
        {
            height: 100%;
        }
        body
        {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        #map-container
        {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            min-width:500px;
            min-height:300px;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>    

</head>


<body>
    <div id="map-container"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript"  language="javascript">

        var _map;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 4,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
            _map = new google.maps.Map($("#map-container")[0], mapOptions);

            Load1();
        });

        // information from data base
        var points = [{lat:1.2345, lng: 3.45465, id: 1}, {lat:-1.45467, lng: 3.54645, id:2}, {lat:2.2345, lng: -4.45465, id:3}, {lat:-2.45467, lng:-4.54645, id:4}];

        //very little global variables (only what you really need to be global)
        var MarkersCollection;

        // the custom marker object with all what you need to show along with your marker
        // and some methods in the prototype that help to manage the object
        function MyMarker(point, id, info) {
            //for the closure                
            var that = this;
            that.id = id;
            that.point = point; // your point
            that.marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: that.point });
            that.info = info; // other information if you need it

            // add the listener to click
            google.maps.event.addListener(that.marker, "click", function() {
                // call onMarkerClick with variable 'that' being the local keyword 'this' within onMarkerClick method
                that.onMarkerClick.call(that);
            });
        }
        MyMarker.prototype.addMarkerToMap = function (map) {
            this.marker.setMap(map);
        };
        // expose getPosition method
        MyMarker.prototype.getPosition = function () {
            return this.marker.getPosition();
        };
        MyMarker.prototype.onMarkerClick = function () {
            //go to the url
            window.location.href = 'http://yourhotels.com/hotel.php?id=' + this.id;
            // or open link in a new window
            window.open('http://yourhotels.com/hotel.php?id=' + this.id);
        };
        MyMarker.prototype.removeMarkerFomMap = function () {            
            this.marker.setMap(null);
        };

        // the collection of custom markers with the methos that help to manage the collection
        function MyMarkerCollection() {
            this.collection = [];
        }
        MyMarkerCollection.prototype.add = function (marker) {
            this.collection.push(marker);
        };
        MyMarkerCollection.prototype.removeAllMarkers = function () {
            for (var i = 0; i < this.collection.length; i++) {                
                this.collection[i].removeMarkerFomMap();
            }
        };
        MyMarkerCollection.prototype.focusAllMarkers = function () {
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            for (var i = 0; i < this.collection.length; i++) {
                bounds.extend(this.collection[i].getPosition());
            }
            _map.fitBounds(bounds);
        };


        // your load function
        function Load(points) {

            if (!MarkersCollection) {
                MarkersCollection = new MyMarkerCollection();
            }
            else {
                MarkersCollection.removeAllMarkers();
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
                var point = new google.maps.LatLng(points[i].lat, points[i].lng),
                    id = points[i].id; // the id
                // create markers
                var marker = new MyMarker(point, id, "your html");
                marker.addMarkerToMap(_map);
                MarkersCollection.add(marker);
            }
            // focus all markers
            MarkersCollection.focusAllMarkers();
        }

        // for the demo sake
        function Load1() {
            Load(points);
        }
        function Remove(){
            if(MarkersCollection)MarkersCollection.removeAllMarkers();
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```